# Elfar logging from multiple sites

Tags: logging

I have a webapp with about 40 users. Each user have their own database.

I then have to implement some error logging, and been looking at elfar.

Does anyone know if I could implement it so I can see which user caused the error so I could help them?

And, is it posible to have the elfar website moved from my site and to another domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if I could implement it so I can see which user caused the error so I could help them?

ELFAR stores the Username, which is retrieved from the `IPrincipal` object and is displayed in the ELFAR UI.

> And, is it posible to have the elfar website moved from my site and to another domain?

As long as the data source for the `IErrorLogProvider` is the same, then it shouldn't be a problem.